# Active Record association links, but can't assign values

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm setting up permissions for each user to determine what access they have to certain data. I have a `user` model and a `permission` model that is set up with a `has_many` and `belongs_to` association like so:

**app/models/permission.rb**

```
class Permission < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end
```

**app/models/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :permission
end
```

The migration I used to set up this table is as follows:

**db/migrate/create_permissions.rb**

```
class CreatePermissions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :permissions do |t|
      t.string :group
      t.string :can_see
      t.string :cant_see

      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_column :users, :permissions_id, :integer
  end
end
```

The problem comes when I go into the Rails console. A sample session may look like this:

```
irb(main):001:0> User.column_names
=> ["id", "name", "email", "created_at", "updated_at", "password_digest", "remember_digest",
  "admin", "activation_digest", "activated", "activated_at", "reset_digest", "reset_sent_at",
  "last_active_at", "permissions_id"]
irb(main):002:0> User.first.permissions_id
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
=> 3
irb(main):003:0> User.first.permission
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
=> nil
irb(main):004:0> Permission.where(id: 3)
  Permission Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "permissions".* FROM "permissions" WHERE "permissions"."id" =
  ?  [["id", 3]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Permission id: 3, group: "CA", can_see: "Some stuff", cant_see:
  "Some stuff", created_at: "2015-06-22 12:28:55", updated_at: "2015-06-22 12:28:55">]>
irb(main):005:0> User.first.permission.group
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
NoMethodError: undefined method `group' for nil:NilClass
```

Commands like `User.first.permissions_id` return values and that value should be a foreign key for the `Permission` model, but running `User.first.permission` returns `nil`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your column should be `permission_id`, not permissions_id. That is why AR doesn't find the related model.

Comment: Singular vs plural column/variable names will be the death of me. I knew it'd be something simple like this, thanks much!

Comment: I tried, but I get a message that says "You can except an answer in 8 minutes." Still somewhat new to SO, any idea why this buffer is in place?

Comment: This seems to explain it: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250132/why-cant-i-accept-an-answer-in-the-first-15-minutes-after-asking-the-question

Comment: I guess I could see why that's in place. Slightly bothersome in this situation where I don't think anyone could come up with a better answer, but I see why it's in place. I'll be sure to accept it as soon as I can.